# ¿Como convertir Filas en Columnas SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL Server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que los *CODIGO_USUARIO* se muestren como columnas y los Items (*Abanico Mesa, Abanico Techo, etc*) se muestren como filas.

Comment: Lo mas sencillo que veo sería girar la pantalla del ordenador 90º, ya que si no me equivoco, para hacer lo que quieres habría que anidar tantos selects como columnas tenga tu tabla, y por pocos datos que tengas, será una consulta muy muy pesada.

Comment: Estaría bueno, si podes armate una tabla ya sea en excel, o donde sea, del resultado que buscas, así es más fácil interpretar lo que quieres

Comment: Puedes hacer un pivot, utilizando este [ejemplo](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/), o, haz un reporte, usando reporting services o RDLC reports, utilizando columnas agrupadas, mira este [ejemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/reporting-services/report-design/understanding-groups-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: ¿Cuantos `CODIGO_USUARIO` vas a mostrar?  te sugiero que muestres  la estructura de la tabla y la consulta SQL para generar la imagen que muestras.

Comment: Son 436.632 CODIGO_USUARIO y la consunlta es un simple: SELECT * FROM TempCensoElect

Comment: O sea que estarías hablando de  436.632 columnas? El limite de columnas por select es de 4,096. Entiendo que no podrías.